# sequelize findAll is not checking if current user liked a post

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a scenario in which if you like a post, it will change

`liked:false` to  `liked:true`

This liked is based if the current user liked the post. The problem is when a new user signs up, it will still show `liked` being true despite the new user NOT liking the post.

How would i be able to check if the current user liked the post ? I don't think my logic is somewhat right as far as checking if the current user liked the post.

I want to keep the `findAll` functionality, i should get all posts, not just by the current user.

Sorta like instagram, or facebook.

this is posts array

[image]

and this is how im liking a post

**likePost**

```
likePost: async (req: any, res: Response) => {
    const created = await models.Likes.findOne({
      where: {
        userId: req.session.user.id,
        resourceId: req.params.id
      }
    });
    console.log(created);
    const post = await models.Post.findOne({ where: { id: req.params.id } });
    // if like not created then do this
    if (!created && post) {
      await models.Likes.create({
        userId: req.session.user.id,
        resourceId: req.params.id
      }).then(() => {
        post.increment("likeCounts", { by: 1 });
        post.update({ liked: req.session.user.id ? true : false });
        res.status(200).send({
          message: "You liked this post"
        });
      });
      // else if post does not exist
    } else if (!post) {
      res.status(200).send({
        message: "there is not post to be liked"
      });
    } else {
      // else if a like does exist destroy like
      await models.Likes.destroy({
        where: {
          userId: req.session.user.id
        }
      }).then(() => {
        post.decrement("likeCounts", { by: 1 });
        res.status(200).send({
          message: "You unliked this post"
        });
      });
    }
```

this is how im getting the posts.

**getPosts**

```
 getPosts: async (req: any, res: Response) => {
    await models.Post.findAll({
      include: [
        { model: models.User, as: "author", attributes: ["username"] },
        { model: models.Likes }
      ],
      order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
      limit: 6
    }).then(posts => {
      res.json(posts);
    });
  },
```

**Post.js(model)**

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var Post = sequelize.define("Post", {
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        postContent: DataTypes.STRING,
        liked: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: false
        },
        likeCounts: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0,
            validate: {
                min: 0,
            }
        },
        authorId: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }, {});
    Post.associate = function (models) {
        Post.belongsTo(models.User, {
            as: "author",
            foreignKey: "authorId",
            onDelete: "CASCADE"
        });
        Post.hasMany(models.Likes, {
            foreignKey: "resourceId",
            timestamps: false,
            targetKey: "id",
            onDelete: "CASCADE"
        });
    };
    return Post;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So by following @doublesharp help, i was able to determine if the current user liked the post or not, by using a sequelize data type [VIRTUAL](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/data-types.js~VIRTUAL.html), along with using [getDataValue](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/instance/#getdatavaluekey-any)

updated code

*Post(model)*

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var Post = sequelize.define("Post", {
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        postContent: DataTypes.STRING,
        liked: {
            type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: false,
            get: function () {
                return this.getDataValue('Likes').length ? true : false;
            }
        },
        likeCounts: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0,
            validate: {
                min: 0,
            }
        },
        authorId: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }, {});
    Post.associate = function (models) {
        Post.belongsTo(models.User, {
            as: "author",
            foreignKey: "authorId",
            onDelete: "CASCADE"
        });
        Post.hasMany(models.Likes, {
            foreignKey: "resourceId",
            timestamps: false,
            targetKey: "id",
            onDelete: "CASCADE"
        });
    };
    return Post;
};
//# sourceMappingURL=post.js.map
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the bug you are seeing is because you are not resolving the promises that are returned by:

```
    post.increment("likeCounts", { by: 1 });
    post.update({ liked: req.session.user.id ? true : false });
```

This means that the response will be send before those queries execute. The `post.liked` value will be set to true any time there is a `user.id` on the session. You may want to consider using transactions to roll back some of the earlier queries if later ones fail. I would also recommend using `Promise.all()` to make concurrent queries (it will be faster) and use `async/await` exclusively without mixing in `thenables`.

```
likePost: async (req: any, res: Response) => {
  // fetch created and post at the same time
  const [ created, post ] = await Promise.all([
    models.Likes.findOne({
      where: {
        userId: req.session.user.id,
        resourceId: req.params.id
      }
    }),
    models.Post.findOne({
      where: {   
        id: req.params.id
      }
    }),
  ]);

  // no post, no updates
  if (!post) {
    return res.status(200).send({
      message: "there is no post to be liked"
    });
  }

  // we are going to make updates, so use a transaction, you will need to reference sequelize
  let transaction;
  try {
    transaction = await sequelize.transaction();

    if (!created && post) {
      // use Promise.all() for concurrency
      await Promise.all([
        models.Likes.create({
          userId: req.session.user.id,
          resourceId: req.params.id
        }, { transaction }),
        post.increment("likeCounts", { by: 1, transaction }),
        post.update({ liked: req.session.user.id ? true : false }, { transaction }),
      ]);

      await transaction.commit();

      return res.status(200).send({
        message: "You liked this post"
      });
    }

    await Promise.all([
      models.Likes.destroy({
        where: {
          userId: req.session.user.id
        }
      }, { transaction }),
      post.decrement("likeCounts", { by: 1, transaction }),
    ]);

    await transaction.commit();

    return res.status(200).send({
      message: "You unliked this post"
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (transaction) {
      await transaction.rollback();
    }
    console.log('There was an error', err);
    return res.status(500);
  }
}
```

To only return `Likes` for the current user on the getPost()

```
getPosts: async (req: any, res: Response) => {
  const posts = await models.Post.findAll({
    include: [
      { model: models.User, as: "author", attributes: ["username"] },
      // limit the likes based on the logged in user
      { model: models.Likes, required: false,
        where: { userId: req.session.user.id },
      },
    ],
    order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
    limit: 6
  });

  return res.json(posts);
},
```

Comment: i will give this code a shot and let you know how it went. thanks alot doublesharp this has been bothering me for the longest.

Comment: im getting `{ error: column "likeCounts" does not exist` when it does exist in the posts array, would you have an idea what could be causing this ?

Comment: you called models.Likes.findOne twice in the promise, was that accidental

Comment: The logic for liking the post is working, however a new user is signed up and logged in, its showing posts that have been liked, when the new user never liked i, so do you think the getPosts should be modified in such a way that it checks if the current user liked the post ?

Comment: @BARNOWL yes that was an error, you corrected it.... correctly :)

Comment: This line `post.update({ liked: req.session.user.id ? true : false }, { transaction }),` sets the post.liked = true, and then you never remove it if the last "Likes" entry is removed, which is probably not that big of a deal tbh. If you want to just get the Likes for that user add `required: false, where: { userId: req.session.user.id }` to the Likes include.

Comment: hmmmm, All posts are coming back as `liked:true` when running your `getPosts` code.  

I'm looking for it function as similar to a instagram feed where a picture is only filled hearted if you liked it, for example an api response fetches all the posts, and the data properties have a `likedByuser` property, it needs to check if the current user liked it or not.

Comment: in this code, posts array `liked` really means liked by current user(you) does this make sense ? 

the getPosts should fetch all the posts, not filtering through posts. but get all posts, and check if the `liked` property has been liked by you or not.

Comment: Would you have an idea, on how this could be implemented ? appreciate  your help by the way

Comment: You updated the answer just now ? looks the same. If thats the case, yeah i tried this out already, and that what my last comment was referring too.

Comment: The `post.liked` is shared between all users, so if you want to set it per user you can use a `DataType.VIRTUAL` on the Model and use a custom get() to check `this.getDataValues('likes').length` or similar to return true/false.

Comment: so the post.liked property has a type of boolean, just switch it to Datatype.virtual right ? I shared the post model.

Comment: hello  @doublesharp , i have a question about this code. In my database next to each post i have liked:true, does this apply to all users or only to the users that actually liked the post?

Comment: @BARNOWL can you please have a look at my comment.

Comment: i keep getting this error (node:84485) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: @kd12345 if it is on the posts it doesn't sound like it is per user, you would need a many to many relationship for that. I recommend posting your own question though, the errors are specific to your code.